# How can I test my SpringBoot RestController using a MockMvc when I rely on a Spring Validator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

In my rest-controller I am validating the input JSON with a custom Spring validator class.

When I now want to write unit test for the controller then I am getting the error that my Validator could not be found...

I am using constructor injecting for the two components in my rest-controller.

```
@Autowired
public JobController(JobValidator jobValidator, JobService jobService) {
    this.jobValidator = jobValidator;
    this.jobService = jobService;
}
```

And here my corresponding Test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(JobsController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MailMonitorJobControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private JobService jobService;

@Test
public void givenJobs_whenGetJobs_thenReturnJsonArray() throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job("TEST");
    List<Job> allJobs = Arrays.asList(job);
    Mockito.when(jobService.getAllJobs()).thenReturn(allJobs);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/test")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}

}
```

Appreciate any help, hints or suggestions!

Comment: You have mocked only jobService but not JobValidator

Comment: yeah that was it! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @pvpkiran! I had to add the JobValidator also as a Mock!

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(JobsController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MailMonitorJobControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private JobService jobService;

@MockBean
private JobValidator jobValidator;

@Test
public void givenJobs_whenGetJobs_thenReturnJsonArray() throws Exception {
Job job = new Job("TEST");
List<Job> allJobs = Arrays.asList(job);
Mockito.when(jobService.getAllJobs()).thenReturn(allJobs);
mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/test")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}

}
```